# "type" object is not subscriptable error in Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm a newbie to Python Selenium environment. This is my piece of code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import unittest

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver= webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

    def test_Login(self):
        driver=self.driver
        facebookUsername ="somoe@gmail.com"
        facebookPassword ="basabasa"
        emailFieldID     = "email"
        passFieldID      = "pass"
        loginButtonXpath = "//input[@value= 'Log In']"
        fbLogoXpath      = "(//a[contains(href , 'logo')])[1]"

        emailFieldElement    = WebDriverWait[driver, 10].until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldID))
        passwordFieldElement = WebDriverWait[driver, 10].until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldID))
        loginButtonElement   = WebDriverWait[driver, 10].until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_xpath(loginButtonXpath))

        emailFieldElement.clear()
        emailFieldElement.send_keys(facebookUsername)
        passFieldElement.clear()
        passFieldElement.send_keys(facebookPassword)
        loginButtonElement.click()
        loginButtonElement=WebDriverWait[driver, 10].until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath(fbLogoXpath))

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
if __name__=='__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

This code loads Facebook when it runs but does not autofill the email and password area and returns with the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to index a `WebDriverWait` object instead of initializing it.

You should replace all the:

```
WebDriverWait[driver, 10]
```

with

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
#            ^          ^
```

---

Reference:

[Selenium explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: @TaimurKhurram If the answer helped, you may consider accepting it

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Accepting answers is a so much hard task... imho ;-B (sarcasm on)